# Text to speech from an epub or pdf ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I have tried source code from [this link](https://github.com/PaulHalliday/Ionic3_TextToSpeech) for converting text to speech from an input box. This works when text is typed into a text box.

Now the issue I am facing is using the same functionality on an epub file or PDF file to read out all the text written on the document using ionic 3. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I supouse you need first extract the text of a .pdf or epub and call to the function this.tts.speak(yourVariable);

Comment: Oh ok. Are there any libraries I can use to extract the text?